# Passing parameters in Angular js Getters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am using angular 1.6.x

I have a list of checkboxes which maintain their state using a variable (selectedJobIds). The variable contains selected job ids, like,

```
$scope.selectedJobIds = {
 23: true,
 56: true,
 47: false
}
```

Now, I need to check the checkboxes which exist in this object and have value true. Also, the checkboxes should be checked even if they don't exist in the object.

Right now, it is not able to differentiate between non-existent id and id with false value. It unchecks both of them.

Tried Approaches:
1) I tried to implement ternary condition in 
`ng-model="(angular.isDefined(selectedJobIds[job.iid])?selectedJobIds[job.iid]:true)"`

But it throws syntax error.

2) I tried using getter/setter of ng-model-options
But the problem is that I can't able to pass job id to the getter function. Also, I am not able to get the scope of the current element, so I can access its value. So, I can use this id to detect its existence and non-existence in selectedJobIds variable.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled filtered-trucks-ul">
  <li ng-repeat="job in dType track by $index" style="vertical-align: middle;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="job_id" value="{{job.iid}}"
             ng-click="selectFilterJob()"
             ng-model="selectedJobIds[job.iid]" />
      <img src="23.png">
      {{ job.rref + ' (' +job.iid+ ')' | uppercase }}
      </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.checkedFilteredJobs = {
    getterFunc: function(newName) {
        console.log(newName)
        // if(angular.isDefined($scope.selectedJobIds[id]))
        // {
        //    return $scope.selectedJobIds[id];
        // }
        // else {
        return true;
        // }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-init to initialize missing properties:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myAppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.dType = [{iid: 23}, {iid: 56}, {iid: 47}, {iid: 1234}, {iid: 888}];
  $scope.selectedJobs = {
    23: true,
    56: true,
    47: false
  };

  $scope.initMissing = function(job) {
    if (!$scope.selectedJobs.hasOwnProperty(job.iid))
      $scope.selectedJobs[job.iid] = true
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="job in dType track by $index">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-init="initMissing(job)" name="job_id"
             ng-model="selectedJobs[job.iid]" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```